# How to create table3 from table1 and table2 in MySQL 5.7.12

Tags: mysql

Consider tables `table1`, `table2`, `table3`

`table1`:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | b    |
|    3 | c    |
+------+------+
```

`table2`:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    2 | b    |
|    3 | c    |
|    4 | d    |
+------+------+
```

`table3`:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | b    |
|    3 | c    |
|    4 | d    |
+------+------+
```

How do I create `table3` out of `table1` and `table2` in MySQL 5.7.12?  What is the name of this operation?

Here is code to create `table1` and `table2`:

```
DROP TABLE table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    col1 BIGINT,
    col2 TEXT
);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 'a');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 'b');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3, 'c');
DROP TABLE table2;
CREATE TABLE table2 (
    col1 BIGINT,
    col2 TEXT
);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2, 'b');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (3, 'c');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (4, 'd');
```

Using the `UNION DISTINCT` operation:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 SELECT * FROM table1 UNION DISTINCT SELECT * FROM table2;
```

Comment: mysql doesn't support full outer join. It will be union

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For inserting into table 3 you need

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
    col1 BIGINT,
    col2 TEXT
);
insert into table3
select * from table1
UNION
select * from table2;
```

Comment: Not me, but some people automatically downvote answers to poor questions. This question is poor because the OP didn't make any attempt to solve it himself.